# 2 parallel synchronous tasks and ManualResetEvent. How to start/stop any task, but another will still doing a job

Tags: c#, .net

i have 2 continious repeating parallel synchronous Tasks, which are doing some job with period 2 and 3 seconds, and i have to synchronize them - so that, every 6 second they do jobs at same time. I did it with private readonly ManualResetEvent  _syncEvent.

But! i want to have opportunity to stop any of task any time. Now its problem - another Task will stop too (ProcessTask1 will wait _syncEvent.WaitOne() infinitely). How can i avoid it? Thanks.

```
private void ProcessTask1(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // Synchronize with Task2
            _syncEvent.Set();

            if (_periodTask1.Add(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000)) <= _systemClock.UtcNow)
            {
                //someJob
                _periodTask1 = _systemClock.UtcNow;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void ProcessTask2(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // Wait for synchronization with Task Task1
            _syncEvent.WaitOne();
            if (_periodTask2.Add(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000)) <= _systemClock.UtcNow)
            {
                //someJob
                _periodTask2 = _systemClock.UtcNow;
            }
            // Reset the event for the next synchronization
            _syncEvent.Reset();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 24.03.2024** i refactored ProcessTask2, added if/else for _syncEvent, it works, but i think wrong desicion.

```
private void ProcessTask2()
{
        while (!cancellationTokenTask2.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // Wait for synchronization with Task2, if another Task2 is not cancel
            if (cancellationTokenTask1.IsCancellationRequested)
                _syncEvent.Set();
            else 
                _syncEvent.Wait();
                    
            if (_periodTask2.Add(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000)) <= _systemClock.UtcNow)
            {
                //someJob
                _periodTask2 = _systemClock.UtcNow;
            }
            // Reset the event for the next synchronization
            _syncEvent.Reset();
        }
}
```

Comment: You pass cancellationToken, so I would pass a different cancellation token to task1 and task2 and after that it will be possible to cancel concrete task.

Comment: No(. If i cancel ProcessTask 1, ProcessTask2 will wait _sync Event.WaitOne() infinitely.

Comment: If you use a `ManualResetEventSlim` instead of a `ManualResetEvent` , you can pass a cancellation token to `Wait`, which allows you to cancel the wait.

Comment: If i use ManualResetEventSlim with task1 cancellation token, than it cancel task2 too, on the contrary, I need to continue it.

Answer (score 2):

Everything becomes much, much simpler if you simply have a single method responsible for scheduling all of the work, rather than two separate methods each trying to synchronize with each other.  Doing this means the timing code only needs to be in one place, and it gives you tons of control over how they execute, making it easy to ensure they run in a particular order and don't stray out of sync with each other over time due to timing inaccuracies (since there is only ever a single "clock" and not two).

It also means you no longer have shared data used from multiple threads, which would require proper synchronization which your code lacks, meaning it has race conditions.

Also, it's quite problematic to have a busy loop like that to wait for long periods of time; it chews up a ton of system resources doing nothing productive.

```
private async Task ProcessTasks(CancellationToken task1Token, CancellationToken task2Token)
{
    unchecked
    {
        int counter = 0;
        while (!task1Token.IsCancellationRequested || task2Token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            if (!task1Token.IsCancellationRequested && counter % 2 == 0) DoTask1();
            if (task2Token.IsCancellationRequested && counter % 3 == 0) DoTask2();
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

If the problem generalizes beyond just these two specific tasks you can generalize it further to have a class describing the period with it's own token and delegate and just iterate through all of them each "tick".  At this point you've firmly decoupled each of the specific jobs from each other and also from the actual scheduler itself.

```
public class Job
{
    public CancellationToken CancellationToken { get; init; } = CancellationToken.None;
    public Action Action { get; init; }
    public int Period { get; init; }
}
private async Task ProcessTasks(IEnumerable<Job> jobs)
{                
    var jobsLocal = jobs.ToList();
    unchecked
    {
        int counter = 0;
        while (jobsLocal.Any())
        {
            jobsLocal.RemoveAll(job => job.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested);
            foreach (var job in jobsLocal)
            {
                if (counter % job.Period == 0) job.Action();
            }
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great!, but i created a continuous synchronous tasks, because i cant change thread id, until task stopped. This is the rule. And, if i run task every 1 second, id will changed.

Comment: @Roman Then you can either run the method from a `SynchronizationContext` (the main reasons you'd need to stay on a single thread are typically going to do this for you) or use `Thread.Sleep` if you can't/won't use a sync context.

Comment: SynchronizationContext  is new for me, it allows me to run task in constant id?

Comment: @Roman It is the mechanism that determines how an `await` executes it's continuations.  Pretty much any framework that requires using a particular thread is going to set one that schedules work to that thread, so whatever you're using that forces you to use a particular thread should already be setting it, unless you're rolling your own framework of some kind (which sounds dubious), in which case you'd want to create one and set it as the current context.